# Showing/dismissing a walkthrough - iOS Application structure

Tags: ios, walkthrough, application-structure

I need to present the classic walkthrough when the Application get launched the first time but, with the implementation that I have in mind, I end up with a structure that keeps the walkthrough as first controller of the hierarchy... and I don't like that. Here is a description of my implementation:

**1)** In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` I check UsereDefault to catch the first launch

**2)** If is the first launch I substitute the `rootViewController` of the `window` with the walkthrough

**3)** When the walkthrough is finished I present the `first view controller of the App`

The problem is with point **3**. Presenting the controller from the walkthrough I end up with the whole application presente as modal of the walkthrough... what I want is to completely substitute the walkthrough with the standard first view controller.

Could you suggest a good pattern to show/dismiss a walkthrough?

Comment: Does your app use a nav controller? Does the walk through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you finish Walk-through, replace the `rootViewController` of your window.

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
yourAppDelegate.window.rootViewController = firstVC;
```

Or if you are using storyboard:

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = (FirstViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourFirstVCId"];
yourAppDelegate.window.rootViewController = firstVC;
```

Another option is Show the Walkthrough as modal on top of `FirstViewController` if it's first time.

Comment: Is there a way to perform a smooth transition? changing the rootController that way has a terrible gfx effect.

Comment: You need to write some custom animation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library to implement your walkthrough https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough.